# how to get response in json format using twilio sdk

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am using Twilio's PHP SDK to send SMS. Below is the code:

```
<?php
// Required if your environment does not handle autoloading
require './autoload.php';

// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
$sid = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

// Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
$client->messages->create(
    // the number you'd like to send the message to
    '+XXXXXXXXXX',
    array(
        // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
        'from' => '+XXXXXXXX',
        // the body of the text message you'd like to send
        'body' => 'Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!'
    )
);

**Response:
[Twilio.Api.V2010.MessageInstance accountSid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX sid=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]**
```

How I can get the response in JSON Format?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: anyone please..

Comment: You can construct the API call yourself to get the JSON response. Can I ask why you need the JSON and why the object the helper library doesn't give you what you need?

Comment: From Twilio documentation: "Json: If your function returns valid Json, you should be able to access it via widgets.MY_WIDGET_NAME.parsed"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I have understood your intent properly, however, I've created [a new GitHub repository](https://github.com/settermjd/StackOverflowTwilioPHPExamples) which I hope gives you the information that you're after, if you're still interested.

The `MessageInstance` object which the call to `$client->messages->create()` returns won't return anything of value when passed to `json_encode()`. This is because the relevant properties are contained in a protected property, so `json_encode()` cannot access them.

One option to get around this is to use a class which implements [JsonSerializable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) and returns a JSON representation of a `MessageInstance` object, such as [JsonMessageInstance](https://github.com/settermjd/StackOverflowTwilioPHPExamples/blob/main/src/JsonMessageInstance.php).

Have a look at the code and let me know if this does what you wanted.

Comment: Applause to you, amazing answer.

Comment: Thank you, @AresStavropoulos. That's very kind of you to say.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is:

```php
$json_string = json_encode(</POST|GET>);
```

Use the `$_POST` or `$_GET` [super globals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and you get a json string format.

e.g.

```php
/*
 * Imagine this is the POST request
 *
 * $_POST = [
 *     'foo' => 'Hello',
 *     'bar' => 'World!'
 * ];
 *
 */


$json_string = json_encode($_POST); // You get → {"foo":"Hello","bar":"World!"}
```

In this way you encode the values in a [JSON](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) representation.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio provides a response which while it can't directly be piped into json_encode, includes a php magic get method which can be used to read the JSON response properties:

```php
  $response = $twilio->messages->create(
      $sms_enrollment->sms_number,
      array(
          'from' => TWILIO_NUMBER,
          'body' => $message
      )
  );
  echo $response->sid . PHP_EOL; // Prints the message SID
  echo $response->body . PHP_EOL; // Prints the message body
  echo $response->status . PHP_EOL; // Prints the message status (probably "queued")
```

You can use these to create your own object and encode / save that:

```php
$saveThis = new stdClass;
$saveThis->sid = $response->sid;
$saveThis->status = $response->status;
$saveThis->body = $response->body;
$json = json_encode($saveThis); // {"sid":"SMe3e123456789123456789a1","status":"queued","body":"hello world!"}
```

You can find the full list of accessible properties in the [Twilio repo](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/main/src/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/MessageInstance.php). Look inside the `public function __construct` section for `$this->properties =`

Also additionally, you may want to wrap your call to `$twilio->messages->create()` in an [exception handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) since it can throw an exception if the destination phone number is invalid.